Extract alphabetic_string from a field in Teradata
I have a table (table1) with some columns say (col1, col2, col3). I am trying to extract alphabetic_string from col1. The example data in Col1 is
ABCDEF, GON-F RFF RED, IV CATH INTRO 22G X 1", BD NEED/27G X 1/2"
The output I am expecting is
ABCDEF
GON-F RFF RED
IV CATH INTRO
BD NEED

Define the characters you want to keep in a character class and negate it: REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '[^a-zA-Z -]')
